# How to unpack a list of indefinite length

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list of tuples:

```
my_lst = [('2.0', '1.01', '0.9'), ('-2.0', '1.12', '0.99')]
```

I'm looking for a solution to unpack each value so that it prints out a comma separated line of values:

```
2.0, 1.01, 0.9, -2.0, 1.12, 0.99
```

The catch is, the lenght of lists vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `join` twice:

```
>>> lis=[('2.0', '1.01', '0.9'), ('-2.0', '1.12', '0.99')]
>>> ", ".join(", ".join(x) for x in lis)
'2.0, 1.01, 0.9, -2.0, 1.12, 0.99'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use can use itertools `chain(..)`.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> my_lst = [('2.0', '1.01', '0.9'), ('-2.0', '1.12', '0.99')]
>>> list(chain(*my_lst))
['2.0', '1.01', '0.9', '-2.0', '1.12', '0.99']
```

And then join them with a ",".

```
>>> ",".join(list(chain(*my_lst)))
'2.0,1.01,0.9,-2.0,1.12,0.99'
```

Comment: I'd use `chain.from_iterable` instead though it doesn't really matter much in this application.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in my_lst:
    for j in i:
        print j, ", "
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also the standard 2-D iterable flattening mechanism:

```
>>> ', '.join(x for y in lis for x in y)
'2.0, 1.01, 0.9, -2.0, 1.12, 0.99'
```

Though I prefer `chain.from_iterable`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.chain`, like so:

```
list(itertools.chain(*lst))
```

or use some function like:

```
def chain(*iters):
    for it in iters:
        for elem in it:
            yield elem
```